# How to save a new data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am very new to R so I am not sure how to save a new data frame in R. May I know how to do it?
I used this code to combine rows in my data frame.

```
my_data %>% 
  bind_rows(my_data)
```

May I know how to save the changes I made to my data frame, or save it as a new one? Thank you.

Comment: Please read [An Introduction to R](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.pdf)  that comes with your distribution of R. There are many other sources available on-line that you should read, this is one of the simplest earlier questions one can make.

Comment: @Rui Barradas Thank you for sharing the file Rui. I will read the introduction and learn from the basic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
new_data <- my_data%>% bind_rows(my_data)
```

The `<-` can be use create a new name for your dataframe and save it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the data frame in to a file:

```
df_new <- my_data %>%
          bind_rows(my_data)


write.csv(df_new, "C://Users/Name/Folder/data.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Thank you. I think I know how to do how.